# Value error in streamlit even everything is in string format

Tags: python, streamlit

I am new to coding and I have just started Streamlit. I am unable to understand the logic behind the value error here. Can anyone indicate what exactly I am doing wrong? I am trying to create a loan default prediction page using python.

```
# Set page configuration
st.set_page_config(page_title='Loan Default Prediction System', layout='wide', initial_sidebar_state='collapsed')

# Set custom CSS
st.markdown(
    """
    <style>
    body {
        background-color: #ffffff;
    }
    .tabs {
        background-color: #0000ff;
    }
    </style>
    """,
    unsafe_allow_html=True
)

# Load the loan dataset (replace with your own dataset)
df = loan_data = pd.read_csv('Loan_Default.csv')

# Preprocess the dataset
le = LabelEncoder()
loan_data['Status'] = le.fit_transform(loan_data['Status'])  # Encode the target variable


columns= ['ID', 'year', 'loan_limit', 'Gender', 'approv_in_adv','loan_purpose', 'Credit_Worthiness', 'open_credit','business_or_commercial','Interest_rate_spread', 'Upfront_charges', 'Neg_ammortization','interest_only', 'lump_sum_payment','construction_type', 'occupancy_type', 'Secured_by', 'total_units','credit_type', 'co-applicant_credit_type','submission_of_application', 'LTV', 'Region', 'Security_Type']
df.drop(columns,axis=1, inplace =True)
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer()
df[['rate_of_interest', 'term','property_value','income','dtir1']] = imputer.fit_transform(df[['rate_of_interest', 'term','property_value','income','dtir1']])

from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy='most_frequent')
df[['age']] = imputer.fit_transform(df[['age']])

mask=df['property_value']==df['property_value'].max()
df[mask]['loan_amount']

mask = df['income']==df['income'].max()
df[mask]['Status']

mask = df['income']==df['income'].max()
df[mask]['rate_of_interest']

mask = df['income']==df['income'].min()           
df[mask]['Status']

mask = df['income']==df['income'].min()
df[mask]['rate_of_interest'].value_counts()

mask=df['income']<2000

df['income']=df['income'].apply(lambda x: x if x not in mask else df['income'].mean())


# Split features and target variable
X = loan_data.drop('Status', axis=1)
y = loan_data['Status']

# Train the model
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(X, y)

# Streamlit app
st.title('Loan Default Prediction System')

# Input form
st.header('Enter Loan Information')
loan_type = st.selectbox('Loan Type', ['type1', 'type2', 'type3'])
loan_amount = st.number_input('Loan Amount', min_value=0)
rate_of_interest = st.number_input('Rate of Interest', min_value=0.0)
term = st.number_input('term', min_value=0)
property_value = st.number_input('Property Value', min_value=0)
income = st.number_input('Income', min_value=0)
credit_score = st.number_input('Credit Score', min_value=0)
age = st.number_input('Age', min_value=0)

# Predict loan default
input_data = pd.DataFrame({
    'loan_type': [loan_type],
    'loan_amount': [loan_amount],
    'rate_of_interest': [rate_of_interest],
    'term': [term],
    'property_value': [property_value],
    'income': [income],
    'Credit_Score': [credit_score],
    'age': [age]
})
prediction = model.predict(input_data)

# Display prediction result
if st.button('Predict'):
    if prediction == 0:
        st.error('Loan Default: Yes')
    else:
        st.success('Loan Default: No')
```

I understand that we are unable to convert type1 from string to float but why is it considering float to begin with.

Comment: Can you please add the error statement that you got - like on which line from this whole code